# keras - evaluate_generator yielding different accuracy rates with same training data

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, word-embedding

**TL;DR** My model is trained for 1 epochs - for testing purposes. Yet, when evaluated multiple times, it yields a different accuracy every time I run `evaluate_generator` method **with the same training data**. Why does that happen, and is there any way to get the same accuracy rate when evaluating the same trained data on the same model, multiple times?

---

I am working on the linguistic problem of dialogue act classification and my model is based on [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.04250) paper. Using tools provided by `keras` and `keras_contrib` repositories, I am replicating the exact model, but I have a question on why the evaluation gives out a different accuracy rate.

For reference, I trained the model for a single epoch, and then saved the trained model in a file, using the utility `save_load_utils` provided by `keras_contrib` module. However, whenever I run the model with *those* weights, which were trained for a single epoch, I am getting a different accuracy rate. I have tried it for 5-10 times and it ranges between 68% to 74%, which is rather large. As I am loading the pre-trained (i.e. for 1 epoch) model weights, I am expecting to get the same accuracy. (i.e. short of any precision differences of floating-point numbers) However, the variance in the results at this rate suggest that I may have done something incorrectly.

Does anyone have any idea as to why the `model.evaluate_generator` method generates results that are so different each time I run it with the same weight, even though I use the same, 1-epoch-trained model's weights to evaluate it? Is there any way to fix my evaluation code so that the accuracy obtained for the same trained model is the same every time I evaluate? (i.e. factoring in any minor differences due to floating-point arithmetic)

Below is all the relevant code. The code sample *is* a little more lengthy compared to a standard StackOverflow question, but I wanted to include all the relevant portions of the code. Apologies to Python programmers for the length of the code. I am a novice Python programmer and I probably could have coded the entire thing in a more concise, Python-idiomatic way.

Model preparation coda:

```
def prepare_kadjk_model(max_mini_batch_size,
                        max_conversation_length, timesteps, num_word_dimensions,
                        word_to_index, word_vec_dict,
                        num_tags):
    #Hyperparameters
    m = timesteps
    h = timesteps

    model = Sequential()

    dictionary_size = len(word_to_index) + 1

    embedding_weights = numpy.zeros((dictionary_size, num_word_dimensions))
    for word, index in word_to_index.items():
        embedding_weights[index, :] = word_vec_dict[word]

    # define inputs here
    embedding_layer = Embedding(dictionary_size, num_word_dimensions,
                                weights=[embedding_weights],
                                embeddings_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0001))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(embedding_layer,
                              input_shape=(max_conversation_length, timesteps)))

    model.add(TimeDistributed(Bidirectional(LSTM(m // 2, return_sequences=True,
                                            kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0001)))))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.2)))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(GlobalMaxPooling1D()))
    model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(h // 2, return_sequences = True,
                                 kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0001)), merge_mode='concat'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    crf = CRF(num_tags, sparse_target=False, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0001))
    model.add(crf)
    model.compile(optimizer, loss = crf_loss,
                  metrics=[crf_accuracy])
    return model
```

Batch preparation functions:

```
def form_mini_batches(dataset_x, max_mini_batch_size):
    num_conversations = len(dataset_x)

    # Form mini batches of equal-length conversations
    mini_batches = {}
    for i in range(num_conversations):
        num_utterances = len(dataset_x[i])
        if num_utterances in mini_batches:
            mini_batches[num_utterances].append( i )
        else:
            mini_batches[num_utterances] = [ i ]

    # Enforce max_batch_size on previously formed mini batches
    mini_batch_list = []
    for conversations in mini_batches.values():
        mini_batch_list += [conversations[x: x + max_mini_batch_size] for x in range(0, len(conversations), max_mini_batch_size)]

    return mini_batch_list


def kadjk_batch_generator(dataset_x, dataset_y, tag_indices,
                          mini_batch_list, max_conversation_length,
                          timesteps, num_word_dimensions, num_tags,
                          word_index_to_append, tag_index_to_append):
    num_mini_batches = len(mini_batch_list)

    # Shuffle the order of batches
    index_list = [x for x in range(num_mini_batches)]
    random.shuffle(index_list)

    k = -1
    while True:
        k = (k + 1) % len(index_list)
        index = index_list[k]
        conversation_indices = mini_batch_list[index]

        num_conversations = len(conversation_indices)
        batch_features = numpy.empty(shape = (num_conversations, max_conversation_length, timesteps),
                                     dtype = int)
        label_list = []

        for i in range(num_conversations):
            utterances = dataset_x[conversation_indices[i]]
            labels = copy.deepcopy(dataset_y[conversation_indices[i]])
            num_utterances = len(utterances)
            num_labels_to_append = max(0, max_conversation_length - len(labels))
            labels += [tag_index_to_append] * num_labels_to_append
            tags = to_categorical(labels, num_tags)
            del labels

            for j in range(num_utterances):
                utterance = copy.deepcopy(utterances[j])
                num_to_append = max(0, timesteps - len(utterance))
                if num_to_append > 0:
                    appendage = [word_index_to_append] * num_to_append
                    utterance += appendage

                batch_features[i][j] = utterance
                del utterance

            remaining_space = (max_conversation_length - num_utterances, timesteps)
            batch_features[i][num_utterances:] = numpy.ones(remaining_space) * word_index_to_append
            label_list.append(tags)

        batch_labels = numpy.array(label_list)
        del label_list

        yield batch_features, batch_labels
```

Training function:

```
def train_kadjk(model, training, validation, num_epochs_to_train, tag_indices, max_mini_batch_size,
                max_conversation_length, timesteps, num_word_dimensions, num_tags,
                end_of_line_word_index, uninterpretable_label_index):
    training_mini_batch_list = form_mini_batches(training[0], max_mini_batch_size)
    validation_mini_batch_list = form_mini_batches(validation[0], max_mini_batch_size)

    num_training_steps = len(training_mini_batch_list)
    num_validation_steps = len(validation_mini_batch_list)

    early_stop = EarlyStopping(patience = 5)
    change_learning_rate = LearningRateScheduler(learning_rate_scheduler)

    model.fit_generator(kadjk_batch_generator(training[0], training[1], tag_indices,
                                              training_mini_batch_list, max_conversation_length,
                                              timesteps, num_word_dimensions, num_tags,
                                              end_of_line_word_index, uninterpretable_label_index),
                        steps_per_epoch = num_training_steps,
                        epochs = num_epochs_to_train,
                        validation_data = kadjk_batch_generator(validation[0], validation[1],
                                                                tag_indices,
                                                                validation_mini_batch_list, 
                                                                max_conversation_length, timesteps,
                                                                num_word_dimensions, num_tags,
                                                                end_of_line_word_index,
                                                                uninterpretable_label_index),
                        validation_steps = num_validation_steps,
                        callbacks = [early_stop, change_learning_rate])
```

Evaluation function:

```
def evaluate_kadjk(model, testing, tag_indices, max_mini_batch_size, max_conversation_length,
                   timesteps, num_word_dimensions, num_tags,
                   end_of_line_word_index, uninterpretable_label_index):
    testing_mini_batch_list = form_mini_batches(testing[0], max_mini_batch_size)
    num_testing_steps = len(testing_mini_batch_list)
    score = model.evaluate_generator(kadjk_batch_generator(testing[0], testing[1],
                                                           tag_indices,
                                                           testing_mini_batch_list, 
                                                           max_conversation_length, timesteps,
                                                           num_word_dimensions, num_tags,
                                                           end_of_line_word_index,
                                                           uninterpretable_label_index),
                                     steps = num_testing_steps)
    print("len(score):" + str(len(score)))
    print("score:" + str(score))
```

You may navigate [here](https://github.com/ilimugur/short-text-classification) for a fuller perspective of the graduate thesis project I am working on, but I tried to provide all the relevant bits of functionality required for anyone that can help out.

Comment: Given my earlier mis-read, I want a couple of clarifications.  (1) you refer to "I use the same, 1-epoch-trained data".  *Data* are not trained: the *model* is trained (as you described it in the first sentence).  (2) What have you done to check that you're using exactly the same data with each evaluation?  For instance, if there is some function that takes a random sample from a large test set, you could be reasonably getting different results.  Can you print a datum ID for each one as you evaluate?

Comment: Can you try evaluating with a degenerate test set: say, a single input item?  If you get accuracies flipping between 1.0 and 0.0, that would tell you that it's not the same input set each time.

Comment: I updated my question to indicate the correct terminology as to your clarification request (1). As to (2), I am working on a previously studied problem and I am partitioning the dataset before the training ever begins. Simply put, there are N dialogues, and a previous researcher studying the problem [split](https://github.com/Franck-Dernoncourt/naacl2016) this dataset of dialogues in an exact way. I am using the same methodology and the dataset, so my testing data always consists of the same dialogues, which are identified and split from the training data before the training starts.

Comment: For testing, `keras.evaluate_generator` accepts a function yielding test data in batches. (my question actually includes the relevant code) In my case, I make the evaluation function process every batch available, by passing the number of batches I have as the `steps` parameter to the `evaluate_generator` function. As a result, the model should be tested using **all** of the training samples available. Consequently, as long as I use the same testing data, on instances of the model with exactly the same weights, I should get the same accuracy.

Comment: Blast ... it appears that you've covered my first two levels of diagnostic attempt.  I don't mind being wrong ... what I mind is not having a good way to help you from here.  I'm hopeful that someone else can work on this; it's now beyond my current resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dove deep into the Github issues of `keras` and found the probable cause of the error in [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6977#issuecomment-309241595) comment.

Apparently, similar to batch normalization layers, using `Dropout` layers causes variations as I described in the question. `Dropout` layers casues neurons to be dropped during training. So, when the training of the model is finished, not all the neurons in the initially compiled model are present.

If the model weights are saved using the function `keras_contrib.save_load_utils.save_all_weights`, then the model's weights are saved. However, once you terminate that process without saving the final neuron configuration (not just the weights) the final configuration of the model is lost. As stated [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-contrib/blob/master/keras_contrib/utils/save_load_utils.py), `save_all_weights`, which is the function I used to save the model, does not save the configuration of the model itself.

Consequently, if you compile the model within a different process, and load the weights you saved by using `keras_contrib.save_load_utils.load_all_weights`, even if you test the model with the same data you tested it with in the previous run, the newly compiled model has some extra neurons that were dropped out during the training of the original model. This difference in configuration, combined with the fact that they may be (and in this case *are*) initialized with random weights, causes the evaluation to give a different accuracy rate every time it is run.

The solution seems to be in recording not only the weights, but also all the configuration. This can simply be done by using the `save` method of the model instance instead of `keras_contrib.save_load_utils.save_all_weights`. Obviously, to load the entire model back in a different process, `keras.models.load_model` should be used instead of `keras_contrib.save_load_utils.load_all_weights`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of reasons this may happen, each of them descending from the tactic in most DL models of randomizing certain aspects of the process.  Most input routines will include a `shuffle` operation, randomizing the order of the input sets as a way of balancing the early training.  Many model types depend on the initial weights being differentiated in some way (to allow for differentiated training of perceptrons), which is typically done with some randomizing function.

Any of these circumstances will cause different results in training, especially early training.  Ideally, all training runs will *converge* to a very small range of accuracy, but the early results will vary.  This is not considered a problem.  We can't tell whether that's your problem since you didn't supply any execution trace, such as dumping all of your initial weights, or examining the input order.

If you require reproducible results, then you'll want to dig into your support code, identify the places where a RNG (random number generator) is used, and do one of two things:

- replace each RNG call with a static function of your own, *or*
- force a constant random **seed** before the first call is made.

In my career, we've generally gone with setting the random seed, as it's easy to comment out when we're done being control freaks.  :-)  We had to dig into the code several times, as the different layers of our code would sometimes use more than one RNG; we had to force the seed for each of them.  In Python and most other languages, the call is simple, ssuch as

```
random.seed(1)    # Sets 1 as the initial seed for the RNG.
```

Comment: I would understand if different results came out when comparing instances of a model with different weights. But my question described a single-epoch training session, which occurred **once**, followed by saving the network weights, using the utility `keras_contrib.save_load_utils`. Then, each time I try to evaluate, I just load the weights to the model and run the evaluation function - no further training occurs. Since the weights used are the same, I would expect to get the same accuracy every time I evaluate, but I getting a different value each time.

Comment: I see -- you're *not* retraining each time you evaluate.  I read the verb tense differently.  Blasted English!